# drag and drop of HTML5 not working.Although It is not showing any error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to drag an element and drop it in the textbox. However It is not working.I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.textContent);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = data;
  console.log(li);
  // var data=document.createElement('p');
  // data.innerHTML=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  // console.log(data);
  // console.log(typeof(data));
  // ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(li));
  ev.target.appendChild((li));
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<span> <textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="37" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="target1"></textarea> </span>

<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="source">Sencha</div>
```

Comment: how/why are you appending an li to a textarea?

Comment: Instead of 'textarea' use 'div' and style it just looks like a textarea with which background and border.

Comment: Yes I was doing wrong. I created textNode instead of li and it is working now.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you actually want to do is add the dragged text to the text input, instead of creating a new `<li>` element and then trying to add that to the text area. That would work if you were adding it to a `<div>`, for example, but you can't put HTML inside text inputs.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.textContent);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.innerHTML+=data;
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<span> <textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="37" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="target1"></textarea> </span>

<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="source">Sencha</div>
```